# What to serialize in Unity when app pauses

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, onpause

I'm working on a mobile game and the scene contains:

- 3 different gameObjects- each contains a script to a static
  class-singleton (3 classes total)
- 20 gameObject prefabs with properties scripts
- 1 image

What do I need to serialize, when I get an incoming call for example?

By reading the Unity documentation, I can see that there is a [built in serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization-BuiltInUse.html), is that true?

My questions are:

1. Can I serialize the 3 singleton classes? (one of them is the game manager)
   I thought that I can't serialize static classes
2. Does unity use the built-in serialization to store info about the prefab's transform, and other components attached like AudioSource properties, scripts and animation
3. What happens if the animation is pausing when in the middle of playing?

I don't want to lose critical info when pausing a game and starting again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **1.** and **2.**:

Typically, you shouldn't serialize classes like your `GameManager`, or components like `Transform`. Instead, serialize the **values that define their state**. For example, you can serialize `position`, `rotation`, and `scale` (which are simple structures like `Vector3` or `Quaternion`), and set the `transform` with these values after your pause.

**3.**:

You can easily pause your animation with:

```
animator.enabled = false;
```

**Finally**:

Consider using `Time.timeScale` and `Time.fixedDeltaTime` for pausing of your game instead.

Comment: As an example, I serialize some transform data [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/items/Industry.cs#L363-L365). It's deserialized [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/items/Industry.cs#L388), the field being used to store that position, even if no game object gets created immediately (e.g. the player sold off the asset and the GO was destroyed, but when repurchased, we want to place it in the same position).

Comment: It's true but I have a lot of properties for the GameManager class, a lot of variables that get changed during the game.  Also- when resuming the game `OnApplicationPause(true)`, does unity call `Start()` to all my gameobjects on the scene?

Comment: @SHAI there is no shortcut. u have to be able to design your game such that when you load a set of variables, it can resume from it (that is how games usually implement saving and loading). rgd whether `Start()` is called after resuming from `OnApplicationPause()`, why don't u try it yourself? just do a `Debug.Log()`

Comment: It's still not clear to me, I don't need to save info about the game (scores or whatever), my question is- if I still have to save all variables in my game- just in order to continue the game when resuming it (finishing a phone call ) or would all the variables get restarted.  `Debug.Log()` is not good because every device could react different

Comment: @SHAI if u purely need to pause, set `Time.timeScale = 0f` (as I've suggested in the answer). This will pause most of your movement, effects etc. However, I've a feeling u will need to mix this with saving and loading of some state variables.

Comment: I understand but my game isn't dependent on time, it's a puzzle game like Chess, with a board, do I need to save the state of each piece

Comment: @SHAI in that case, u can achieve the effect of pausing without doing anything. however, u have to ensure that the player cannot click or move any pieces while the game is "paused", etc.